# Selecting pixels by specification in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, patterns, selections, photoshop-scripting

I use Photoshop for carpet designing. My typical artwork is 1800 × 2400 pixels with 8 or 10 colors. Each pixel's position and color is important.

The weaving macine which outputs the carpet can't make 1 pix high horizontal single color lines in good quality if the line has length 10 pix or more. A single color pattern can well be 10 pix (or more) wide if it is higher than 1 pix.

See my image sample. I have marked some problematic lines:

[image: Photoshop selection]

Until this I have walked through the image manually and replaced the problematic lines one by one. That's very time consuming job and easily some errors stay unnoticed.

I need a  fast method - maybe a script or Photoshop plugin or separate program - that finds all those 1x10 (or more) single color lines and replaces them with another pattern of the same color. Even automatic finding would be a delight. If I could define also other patterns to be found and replaced, the software add-on would be luxorius.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: There's still a huge amount of not selected areas that are 10 pixel wide, 1 pixel high and have the same color in all 10 pixels. You should tell, what makes your single color 10x1 areas special (=worth to be selected). No software can make the selections for you if you don't tell that basic difference. NOTE: Photoshop knows nothing about plants, beauty or what is important to you in your thoughts. Also Photosop does not see any  relations that cant be said as numbers. So: What makes your 10x1 single color areas more important than those (thousands) that you have not selected?

Comment: Wouldn't this script also pick up the entire background?

Comment: @TimTroiano this isnt script i selected thos areas manually.

Comment: @user287001  i thank u for complete my mean. yeah its correct i want a intelligent selection that select every single color in 1x10 pixels overall my work.

Comment: Still no clearance. Let me quess: The interesting 1x10 or longer areas are surrounded by other colors at least on most of their length. Additionally they are at the end of a stairs pattern of the same color. You want to make the appearance of the curves more pleasant and for that you want to fast way to walk through all problematic parts. OK? What about vertical too gentle curve ends? Find them, too?

Comment: @user28701 let me explain for u. all our designs woven with machine, problem is here. carpet machine has problem with horizontal lines that are 1 width and more than 10 pixels length, even in curves that has a same color stair at the end of themselves. :( so we should double every horizontal line overall the design..

Comment: @user287001  its so time consuming for us. so it isnt for better curves appearance. subject is so more important  than beauty. but suddenly my pic, shows just curves

Comment: I had totally wrong visio. I would have shown how adding a half-tone the curves generally would have smoother appearance. And that's without any new software. This is totally different. Unfortunately I am not a programmer so I can't give your script. But I make an edit suggestion to your question to prevent further misthinking. You can freely reject it.

Comment: @user287001 :) thanx dear

Comment: Would dividing one 1x10 line to two 1x5 lines help - maybe 2 colors but actually same thread in 2 magazines in the machine

Comment: If you're the one designing this than it would seem to me the best solution would be for you to not put these horizontal lines into your design to begin with.

Comment: This can be done, but you need a developer to do it for you as you need to write a plugin.

Comment: @Ryan it may explain to me more and clear?

Comment: @joojaa developer?

Comment: @user287001  actually not, because the designe goes wrong and seems not beauty. my purpose from "double" was add a new same  line above or below of the main line.

Comment: When you say you replaced the problematic lines, are you replacing part of the length with a different color? If so, how do you determine which color? For example, if the plugin finds 15 pixels in a row that are white, it needs to break those down into two groups, one 10 pixels long and the other 5 pixels long. If it leaves the first group white, how does it determine the color for the next 5 pixels?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a complete solution, but I do have some ideas. Getting each of the colours into their own channels should make things easier to interrogate.

You can do this by selecting a pixel or two of a colour (and only that colour), then choose `Select` → `Similar`.

[image: Photoshop select similar]

With all the pixels of a single colour selected, you can now save the selection, which will create a new channel.

Here’s where things get a bit more difficult and hand-wavy. Through some processing, we should hopefully be able to keep the lines that are 10px wide or longer, but remove all others.

Here’s a test pure black and white selection with some varying line lengths. The top two lines are 12px and 10px wide respectively, and the ones underneath are shorter. We’re trying to keep the 10 and 12px lines, but remove the others.

[image]

Duplicating the selection a few times, offsetting it, and using varying opacity for the layers gets us part of the way there. I used 5px offsets and 50% and 33% opacity, plus levels to take the grey pixels back to white (keeping the ones we want).

[image]

Another pass using the same method, but this time with a 3px offset.

[image]

And a final pass, doing exactly what we did in the first pass. I think this should give the required result, and also be able to be automated by recording an action.

[image]

With a good selection, filling those parts of the image with a pattern should be pretty easy. A pattern layer using the newly created mask would work for that.

Here’s a GIF of the steps used. I think it should work with any initial artwork.

[image: GIF process]

Now I think about it, I think this entire structure could be set up using smart objects and smart filters, so you’d just have to replace the contents of the smart object to process it (assuming the source artwork is the same dimensions).

Comment: Whet happens to those placeswhere you have 2 rows exactly on top of each other? Anyway this is just a single for loop if you care to write a plugin.

Comment: @joojaa The offsets are X axis only, so lines above and below aren’t an issue. I think the technique would require 5px padding to be added to the left and right side of the image for it to work in 100% of cases.

Comment: Yes but your supposed to discard results where there same color on 2 lines because that binds the layers together

Comment: Aslso consider using filter > other > custom instead of layers

Comment: @joojaa You’re right about the lines above and below. This is just a partial solution. Maybe those could be tackled in other steps. It really depends on the exact rules (which still seem a little vague to me). Code would be easier, if the OP writes code, but I’m guessing they don’t. At the very least, this could be used to streamline inspection.

Comment: So for example you can replace the layers by a custom filter 1 1 1 1 1 on diagonal run it 2 times and run a threshold of 255. That should be easier to record as a action.

Comment: OK heres how you do it, it still has some kinks, run a vertical custom filter 1 0 1 with scale of 2 over a duplicated layer. invert and multiply with original, run treshold of 255, run horizontal custom filter 1 1 1 1 1 with multiplier of 5 2 times (for width of 10), run threshold 255. OK now we have only the things that are valid. Then run the 1 1 1 1 1 filter again 2 times and take threshold of 1 select white pixels. Mostly done. repeat for all colors.

Comment: @MarcEdwards thanx dear marc from your solution but i had 2 problem with ur idea. at first im not a professional ps user so i need more clear picture and explain for each step. and the 2th problem is my ps version, i use cs6 not cc so many options are different. actually i could do yourr issue till "draw varying line lengths" :(

Comment: @rahabolandian The great news is that all of the things mentioned above are in CS 6. I might be able to craft a document that does all the work for you. @joojaa’s ideas are good too. I’d love to see an answer from them as well… it sounds like it might be a quicker method.